# document_start: access storage synchronously

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

(I looked at various posts on this, but could not find a workable / recent information)

My content script needs to load some settings (that were set by the user from the default_popup) **before page construction starts**.

If I do:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(null, storage => { 
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) return;
  debugger;
```

When the debugger breaks there are already quite a few DOM elements constructed (visible in the 'Elements' tab) to which I could obviously not apply the settings.

Is there a way for the content script to get data from the popup synchronously before any page loading starts?

Comment: that question injects two content script and as far as I could follow it is not the same so I cannot get any answer from it

Comment: It shows how to pass a dynamic value to your content script that runs on document_start.

Comment: it shows untested code that doesn't work :(

Comment: It works, actually, and it's already used in some extensions like Tampermonkey. Make sure you've reloaded the extension.